# Add a Product's Short Description to customer email template? (M2.4)

Tags: magento2.4, order-email

Could anyone kindly suggest how I could have my product's short description shown in a customer order confirmation email?

I am currently running Magento (Community) 2.4.2.

I've attempted to add the following code to my theme @ "THEME/Magento_Sales/templates/items/order/default.phtml".  I get the surrounding HTML code, but no data returned.

```
<td class="item-info<?= ($block->getItemOptions() ? ' has-extra' : '') ?>">
    <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>

    <-- TRYING TO GET SHORT DESCRIPTION HERE -->
    <p class="short-desc"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getShortDescription()) ?></p>

    <p class="sku"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('SKU')) ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
    <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()) : ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
        <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option) : ?>
            <dt><strong><em><?= $block->escapeHtml($option['label']) ?></em></strong></dt>
            <dd>
                <?= /* @noEscape */  nl2br($block->escapeHtml($option['value'])) ?>
            </dd>
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this are greatly appreciated.

*** EDIT TO INCLUDE SOLUTION FROM GOHIL:
Here is the code with the working short description display

```
<?php 
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
?>

<td class="item-info<?= ($block->getItemOptions() ? ' has-extra' : '') ?>">
    <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>

    <-- GET PRODUCT SHORT DESCRIPTION HERE -->
    <p class="short-desc"> <?php echo $product->getShortDescription(); ?></p>

    <p class="sku"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('SKU')) ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
    <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()) : ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
        <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option) : ?>
            <dt><strong><em><?= $block->escapeHtml($option['label']) ?></em></strong></dt>
            <dd>
                <?= /* @noEscape */  nl2br($block->escapeHtml($option['value'])) ?>
            </dd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object method

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
echo $product->getShortDescription();
```

Factory Method

```
<?php
namespace Test\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $_productloader;  


  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader
        
    ) {

       
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```

phtml file code

```
$product=$this->getLoadProduct($item->getProductId());
echo $product->getShortDescription();
```

In Magento 2.1

```
<?php
    namespace Test\Module\Block;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
    class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
     {
          protected $productRepository; 
          protected $_storeManager; 

          public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
          ) {
              parent::__construct($context);

              $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
          }
          public function getProduct()
          {

              $productId=1;
              return $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
          }
      }
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-load-product-by-id/)

Comment: Thanks very much Gohil Rajesh!  

I was successful by using the (above) listed Object Method from Gohil.  Once I added Gohil's code for the object method to my template, I was able to echo the product's short description, no problem.

Comment: Glad it helps !! :)